# ListProperty of custom properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a elegant way of using a `ListProperty` for storing a subclassed `db.Property` type?

For example, the `FuzzyDateProperty` from [this example](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/extending_models.html) uses `get_value_for_datastore()` and `make_value_from_datastore()` to convert its attributes into one `int` that is stored in the datastore.  Since that one `int` is a Python primitive, it seems that you should be able to create a `ListProperty` of `FuzzyDateProperty`.  How?

In my particular case, i've defined a class and helper functions to neatly serialize / deserialize its attributes.  I would like to encapsulate the class as a db.Property, rather than make the implementer handle the relationship between the class and the Model property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended by @mjhm and @Nick, i've subclassed ListProperty to accept any class.  I've [uploaded a generic version to GitHub](https://github.com/fraserharris/ObjectListProperty), named ObjectListProperty.  I use it as a cleaner alternative to using parallel ListProperty's.

ObjectListProperty transparently serializes/deserializes when getting & putting the model. It has an internal serialization method that works for simple objects, but can handle more complex objects if they define their own serialization method. Here's a trivial example:

```
from object_list_property import ObjectListProperty

class Animal():
    """ A simple object that we want to store with our model """
    def __init__(self, species, sex):
        self.species = species
        self.sex = sex if sex == 'male' or sex == 'female' else 'unknown'

class Zoo(db.Model):
    """ Our model contains of list of Animal's """
    mammals = ObjectListProperty(Animal, indexed=False)

class AddMammalToZoo(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # Implicit in get is deserializing the ObjectListProperty items
        zoo = Zoo.all().get()

        animal = Animal(species=self.request.get('species'),
                        sex=self.request.get('sex') )

        # We can use our ObjectListProperty just like a list of object's
        zoo.mammals.append(animal)

        # Implicit in put is serializing the ObjectListProperty items
        zoo.put()
```

Comment: The link is broken and I can't find any evidence that it ever existed :(

Comment: @Thomas Fixed! Thanks for the heads up

Comment: The link is broken again, but I'm guessing this is the same thing: https://github.com/Willet/ObjectListProperty

Comment: Fixed - not sure why it went down.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Types and Property Classes doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html)

> The App Engine datastore supports a
>   fixed set of value types for
>   properties on data entities. Property
>   classes can define new types that are
>   converted to and from the underlying
>   value types, and the value types can
>   be used directly with Expando dynamic
>   properties and **ListProperty** aggregate
>   property models.

My reading of this suggests that you should be able to just specify the extended db.Property as the item_type of the for the ListProperty.  But there is a [logged issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2439) that suggest otherwise.

Assuming that doesn't work, I think the next best thing is probably to subclass ListProperty and manually extend it with getters, setters, and iterators, based on the "get_value_for_datastore" and "make_value_from_datastore" functions for lists with "FuzzyDateProperty" members.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this - ListProperty expects a basic Python type, not a property class. Property classes, meanwhile, expect to be attached to a Model, not another property.

Comment: Nick - is it possible to subclass a datastore value type so that it converts between an object and its datastore representation?

Comment: Like is done here: http://soc.googlecode.com/hg/thirdparty/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py

Comment: @Fraser No, because ListProperty does not operate on properties. You'd have to subclass ListProperty and have it do the conversion.